# How can I create a proportional area stacked bar chart in R?

Tags: r, graph, charts, ggplot2

I would like to create a horizontal proportional stacked bar "chart", using R.

My data is unidimensional. It represents failure rates in successive categories, and looks like this:

```
taskC=c(16, 10, 13, 5, 4, 5, 12)
labels=c("All correct", "1 fail", "2 fails", "3 fails", "4 fails", "5 fails", "All fail")
```

I would like to create something along the lines of the chart at the below URL, though using a different colour graident (topo is fine) and having it horizontal instead of vertical.

http://www.improving-visualisation.org/vis/id=70

I've looked through ggplot and VCD and can't find anything that solves this. A 3d graph would be ideal, though not critical. Although the data can be represented using a pie chart, these don't provide the linear sense of proportion I want, and also don't sufficiently capture the ordinal nature of the data.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583432/plot-stacked-bar-plot-in-r)?  Horizontal stacked plots are covered on [the ggplot2 help page for bar plots](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_bar.html), by the way.

Comment: Also, if you're concerned enough about perception to want to use linear rather than angular representations of your data, you should probably skip the 3D stuff - it doesn't add anything when you're presenting 1D data.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872428/ggplot-stacked-bar-plot-how-to-apply-different-length-color-ramps-to-each-bar/8874378#8874378

Comment: The dupe candidates don't work as well for cumulative representations; thanks for the tip about 3d, in retrospect, I quite agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
barplot(as.matrix(taskC), horiz=TRUE, col=rainbow(7), xaxt="n")
axis(1, labels=labels, at=cumsum(taskC)-(taskC/2))
```